# Convert AWS Default Lambda Logs to Custom JSON

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I converted all my logs in my Lambda to JSON using [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) to look like this:

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2018-10-04T12:24:48.930Z",
    "message": "Logging some data about my app",
    "level": "INFO"
}
```

How can I convert the AWS Default logging to my custom format?
Is this possible? Is there a way to convert that stream?

---

By "Default Logging" I mean this stuff:

```
START RequestId: 7c759123-a7d0-11e8-b4a4-318095fdonutz Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 7c759123-a7d0-11e8-b4a4-318095fdonutz
REPORT RequestId: 7c759123-a7d0-11e8-b4a4-318095fdonutz Duration: 109.21 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 46 MB
```

Comment: Do you want to convert them when logging in cloudwatch or in your custom log monitoring tool ?

Comment: I would like them log in cloudwatch in JSON